# old style cast with multi-word type

Tags: c++

Single word type conversions like `int(x)` will not trigger any warning, but how do I write in similar way for multi-word type like `unsigned long`, `long long`, or `unsigned char`?

Something like `(unsigned long)(x)` will trigger an old-style cast warning.

If the parenthesis is omitted, like `unsigned long (x)`, it's a syntax error.

Assume the variable `x` is just some native type like `int`, `long`, etc.. Definitely type of `x` is not a class or struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `typedef`:

```
typedef unsigned long ulong;

int i;
unsigned long x= ulong(i);
```

It's not an old style cast warning because that's not a cast, you're creating a new `unsigned long` from an `int`.

You can also use `static_cast`:

```
unsigned long y= static_cast<unsigned long>(i);
```

That's a new style cast.